# creating a specific pattern without a nested loop

Tags: java

I have this strange problem where I am supposed to create the following pattern,

```
**
*
*
***
**
**
*
```

by using a single `for` loop, but the problem is I am not even allowed to use conditional statements like `if/else` or even `Array`

The only way I could think of printing this pattern is storing the entire pattern in a variable and then printing it, but this solution makes the implementation of `for` loop useless unless I create two different variables, break the pattern into two parts and then print both of them using `for` loop, but this is rather poor approach.

Can someone please tell me how can this be implemented using a `for` loop using some `automatic` approach rather than storing them in a variable ?

P.S: It was a challenge question presented in a job interview.

**Edit:** I was also told to use any procedural language I want.

Comment: Do you need to print it in console? How many times do you need to print that pattern, is it a parameter? The example you presented, is it the beginning or the middle part of result sequence?

Comment: No other details were provided except a piece of paper with the above pattern printed on it and the instructions saying not to use if statement array or hash tables, and to only using a single for loop to print it. Thats all.

Comment: This would be a great puzzle for [Code Golfing](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Does a `string` count as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a variant of win_wave solution, simpler to understand and to realize on paper. Here the only complex part is the calculation of the `pattern` variable, that is built converting numbers in bits, grouping them togheter in nibbles and finally converted into a single hexadecimal word (see comment in example code).

```
public class Test
{
    // Pattern  1    2    2    3    1    1    2
    // Bin      01   10...10   11...01   01...10
    // Bin      01   1010      1101      0110
    // Hex      1    A         D         6
    // Hex      1AD6    

    static int pattern = 0x1AD6;

    public static int getNumber(int i)
    {
        return (pattern >> i) & 0x03;    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 14; i += 2)
        {
            System.out.println("***".substring(0, getNumber(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you must have a loop, store your pattern in a string, and use a `for` loop to print it character by character:

```
String pattern = "**\n*\n*\n***\n**\n**\n*\n";
for (int i = 0 ; i != pattern.length() ; i++) {
    System.out.print(pattern.charAt(i));
}
```

Of course, printing the same pattern directly is a more direct way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not allowed to use an array, then use a string:

```
String q = "2113221";

for( int i = 0; i < q.length(); i++){
    int p = q.charAt(i)-'0';
    System.out.println("**********************".substring(0, p));
}
```

Comment: `"***"` would be enough here (instead of `"**********************"`).

Answer (score 3):

If to be strict, String is also array of chars. Here is my possible solution:

```java
static void printPattern() {
    for(int v = 187307; v > 0 ; v >>= 1) {
        int b = -(v & 1);
        int cr = '\n' & ~b;
        int star = '*' & b;
        char c = (char) (cr | star);
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a magnificent solution - but I really hope no one is expecting this as a result of a pen-and-paper interview question.

Comment: I hope the same. Howerver it is posible, just takes time to compute right number manually.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the implicit question of the test is: "Find the logic behind the pattern sequence", the sequence of numbers 2 1 1 3 2 2 1 is very near to an iteration of subractions (iteration step minus sum of two last values).

Iterating from 2 to 8 you have the following sequence of numbers:

- 2 - (0 + 0) = 2
- 3 - (2 + 0) = 1
- 4 - (1 + 2) = 1
- 5 - (1 + 1) = 3
- 6 - (3 + 1) = 2
- 7 - (2 + 3) = 2
- 8 - (2 + 2) = 4 (should be 1)

The following program iterates following this idea and build the requested pattern.

I had to add some trick to calculate the last value of sequence because the logic I found calculates 4 as last value instead of 1. The binary operations are needed to convert 4 into 1.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n0 = 0;
        int n1 = 0;

        for(int i = 2; i < 9; ++i)
        {
            int n = i - n0 - n1;
            int p = (n & 3) + (n >> 2);

            System.out.println("***".substring(0, p));

            n0 = n1;
            n1 = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a second variable?

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        String output = "**,*,*,***,**,**,*";

        for (String row : output.split(",")) {
            System.out.println(row);
        }

     }

}
```

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, i am not allowed to use array. Thats why its confusing

Comment: Right, sorry, I change the comment without array.